# C# File.Move won't find existing file?

Tags: c#, file, move, exists, fileinfo

I have a method that unzips files into an 'unzipped' files folder.  Problem is that there are files duplicated in two zip files - so when the second zip file is extracted the process fails as the file name already exists.  I decided to rename the existing file to avoid this problem, but my if(File.Exists...) statement is not picking up files that exist.  This is probably a noob syntax issue?

```
private void UnzipFiles()
{
        sourceDirectory = @"c:\id";
        unzippedDirectory = @"C:\id\z_unzipped";
        processedDirectory = @"C:\id\z_processed";

        // get list of files from directory and unzip them
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
        FileInfo[] infos = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.zip");

        foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
        {
            if (File.Exists(unzippedDirectory + @"\" + f.Name)){
                // rename existing file
                File.Move(unzippedDirectory + @"\" + f.Name, unzippedDirectory + @"\" + f.Name + " renamed by " + f.Name);
            }

            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(f.FullName, unzippedDirectory);
            File.Move(f.FullName, processedDirectory + @"\" + f.Name);
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Use `Path.Combine(unzippedDirectory,f.Name)` instead of `unzippedDirectory + @"\" + f.Name`

Comment: `f.Name` is giving you the name of the zip file that you're about to extract from - not the name of any file contained within that zip file.

Comment: Why do you have `f.Name` in some places and `f.FullName` in other places?

Comment: If you want to check for the files within the archive, use the `OpenRead` method to open the archive, then walk through the entries and use the `FullName` property (together with, as @TimSchmelter says, `Path.Combine`) to check whether the files you're about to extract have conflicts

Comment: Gabe - in some place I can use the full path as per the DirectoryInfo path, but I'm moving the file to other folders hence concat the new path to just the name.

Comment: Side note: Use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` to emit debugging information. That will help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Damien got it. Sometimes the obvious just gets you! Thanks for all the other advice - will use it.